# How to configure GEdit correctly?

Tags: linux, text-editors, gedit

I've installed GEdit, but I find it quite unusable for programming purposes, which plugins are useful for such thing? (e.g.: to enable auto indentation, auto completion, ...)

One of the thins I'm missing is having the line number in a column in the left side, is that possible with GEdit?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

You can install an additional bundle of plugins by running this:

```
sudo apt-get install gedit-plugins
```

The most convienient one that adds is the Snippets plugin.

Answer (score 1):

You can have the lines in the left side by navigating to **Edit -> Preferences** and checking off **Display Line Numbers**. Additional plugins can be grabbed [here](http://live.gnome.org/Gedit/Plugins) and configured under **Edit -> Preferences -> Plugins Tab**.

You can grab Auto Indent [here](http://code.google.com/p/gedit-autotab/) and Auto Complete [here](http://github.com/nagaozen/gedit-plugin-autocomplete/).

Here's a shot of preferences for reference:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Gedit Symbols Browser plugin is a must as well:

http://www.micahcarrick.com/gedit-symbol-browser-plugin.html